# Poisson distribution probabilities are not linear??

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Say I have a Poisson distrribution with mean $7$ per hour. And I want to calculate the probability of a certain number say $2$ happening in that hour. Then the probability would be $\frac{e^{-7}7^2}{2!}$.

Now if I want to calculate the probability of $2$ in half an hour- I could decide to say the mean is really $3.5$ per half hour and then do $\frac{e^{-3.5}3.5^2}{2!}$.

Or I could keep the mean at $7$ per hour and instead say $2$ per half hour is really just the same as $4$ per hour so do $\frac{e^{-7}7^4}{4!}$. As can be guessed these do not give the same answer- when there's an exponential and a factorial term involved- no linear factors would cancel to give the same result as before.

So which is right? Remember I want to calculate the probability of $2$ in half an hour. Thanks.

Comment: 4 per hour doesn't mean 2 per half-hour

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466518/why-cant-we-combine-events-in-a-poisson-distribution?rq=1) is  related.

Comment: @Alex Why not? why then can we take 7 per hour to be 3.5 per half hour then

Comment: You can have 3 occasions in the second half for example

Answer (score 0):

The number of events in a half-hour period has Poisson distribution mean $\frac{7}{2}$. So your first calculation is correct.

Comment: But why?- Why is the second way not the correct way?

Comment: As an extreme example of why you can't multiply by $2$, certainly we cannot say that $0$ per half hour is equivalent to $(0)(2)$ per hour.